# Description Resource Path Location Type Java compiler level does not match the version of the instal

Tags: java, tomcat

There was an error while running tomcat. What was that：

```
Description Resource Path Location Type Java compiler level does not match the version of the instal
```

Comment: Please do not cut out the full error message. Looks like as a java versions issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this error, now according to the following input revised:

1.windows—proferences—java–compiler
[image]

2.windows—proferences—java–Installed JREs
[image]

3.properties—java Compiler
[image]
4.properties—project Facets
[image]